# A difficult determinant

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants

(EDIT: I have removed the denominators I had in a previous version as they were superfluous)

The $N\times N$ determinant 
$$D(a,\vec{b})=\det\left((2N+a+b_j-i-j)!\right)$$
has the nice form
$$D(a,\vec{b})=\prod_{j=1}^N(N+a+b_j-j)!\prod_{i=j+1}^N(b_j-b_i-j+i).$$

Since from the definition it is clear that $D(a,\vec{b})$ is antisymmetric in the variables $x_j=(N+b_j-j)$, it should be proportional to the Vandermonde of the $x$.

I would like to know if the generalization where $a$ is allowed to vary with $i$ has a nice expression as well,
$$D(\vec{a},\vec{b})=\det\left((2N+a_i+b_j-i-j)!\right)=?$$

This is antisymmetric in both $x_j=(N+b_j-j)$ and $y_i=(N+a_i-i)$, so it should be proportional to both Vandermondes of the $x$ and the $y$...

I know Krattenthaler has [this great paper](http://emis.ams.org/journals/SLC/wpapers/s42kratt.pdf) about determinants, but I was not able to find help there.

Comment: Does it factor? I mean, a CAS can factor some expressions..

Comment: Math experiment done with Maple brings nothing of the kind for $N=3, N=4.$ The executed code on demand.

Comment: Your $D(\vec{a},\vec{b})=\det\left((2N+a_i+b_j-i-j)!\right)=? $ was changed  without indicating it in your edit. My pevious comment was about the previous version   of$D(\vec{a},\vec{b})=\det\left((2N+a_i+b_j-i-j)!/(\left( N-i \right) !\, \left( N+a_{{i}}-i \right) !)\right)$.

Comment: @user64494 As I said in the edit, all I did was remove some superfluous denominators. Nothing substantial has changed.

Comment: With $x_i = N+a_i-i$, $y_j = N+b_j-j$, you are asking for $\det((x_i+y_j)!)$. If you multiply the $i$th row by $(x_i!)^{-1}$ and the $j$th column by $(y_j!)^{-1}$, then up to a factor $\prod_i x_i! \prod_j y_j!$, you just need $\det(\binom{x_i+y_j}{x_i})$. The [Lindström-Gessel-Viennot lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindström–Gessel–Viennot_lemma) gives a combinatorial interpretation of the latter determinant in terms of lattice paths between the set of points $\{(-x_i,0) \mid i=1,\dotsc,N\}$ and the set of points $\{(0,y_j) \mid j=1,\dotsc,N\}$.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a solution myself, at least in the case when $a$ and $b$ are partitions.

The determinant can be written as
$$ D=\det((x_i+y_j)!)=\det\left( \int z^{x_i+y_j}e^{-z}dz\right)$$
We resort to the Andreief identity,
$$ \int dz \det(f_{i}(z_{j}))\det(g_{i}(z_{j}))=N!
\det\left(\int f_{i}(z)g_{j}(z)dz\right).$$
This is usually used from left to right, but I used in reverse to write
$$D=\frac{1}{N!}\int dz \det(z_{j}^{x_j})\det(z_{j}^{y_i})\prod_{i=1}^Ne^{-z_i}$$
Now, if $x_i=a_i-i+N$ and $y_i=b_i-i+N$ and if $a\vdash n$ and $b\vdash m$ are partitions, then $\det(z_{j}^{x_j})\det(z_{j}^{y_i})=(V(z))^2s_a(z)s_b(z)$, where $V$ is the Vandermonde and $s$ are the Schur functions. Then
$$D=\frac{1}{N!}\int dz (V(z))^2s_a(z)s_b(z)\prod_{i=1}^Ne^{-z_i}$$

The Littlewood-Richardson coefficients are defined by $s_as_b=\sum_{\rho\vdash n+m} c^\rho_{ab}s_\rho$. Using them we have
$$D=\frac{1}{N!}\sum_{\rho\vdash n+m} c^\rho_{ab}\int dz (V(z))^2s_\rho(z)\prod_{i=1}^Ne^{-z_i}.$$
This is an integral of the Selberg type, and the result is known:
$$\int dz (V(z))^2s_\rho(z)\prod_{i=1}^Ne^{-z_i}=N!\frac{d_\rho}{(n+m)!}\prod_{j=1}^N (\rho_i+N-i)!^2 \quad (\ell(\rho)\le N),$$ where $d_\rho$ is the dimension of the irreducible representation of the permutation group labeled by $\rho$.

Therefore,
$$D=\frac{1}{(n+m)!}\sum_{\substack{\rho\vdash n+m\\\ell(\rho)\le N}} d_\rho c^\rho_{ab}\prod_{j=1}^N (\rho_i+N-i)!^2.$$

Curiously, there are no Vandermondes in this solution.